# Talend - Configure Event monitoring alerting email

Tags: email, configuration, talend

I use TOS8.0.1 and I want to receive an email when there is an error in the log file.

I tried to follow this documentation but it doesn't work.

https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/esb-infra-services-configuration-guide/email

I configured these files:
**org.apache.karaf.decanter.alerting.service.cfg**

`rule.receptionERROR = "{'condition':'message:*','level':'ERROR'}"`

**org.apache.karaf.decanter.alerting.email.cfg**

```
`From email address
from=...

To e-mail address
to=...

Hostname of the SMTP server
host=...

Port of the SMTP server
port=...

enable SMTP auth
auth=false

enable starttls and ssl
starttls=false
ssl=false`
```

Thanks for your help